# When CustomView extens ConstraintLayout and use ConstraintSet in constructor, the constraint not work

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

As the title, my CustomView extend ConstraintLayout, when set constraint  use ConstraintSet in constructor, it not work. i try to postDelayed constraint, it work!

Is there a Function  to put constraint ?

```
    public  class ConstraintAfterInit extends ConstraintLayout{
        LinearLayout view;
        public ConstraintAfterInit(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);

            view = new LinearLayout(context);
            view.setId(View.generateViewId());
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams viewLp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            viewLp.matchConstraintMinHeight = 200;
            view.setLayoutParams(viewLp);
            this.addView(view);
            //layout()

            this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    layout();
                }
            },2000);

        }

        public void layout(){
            ConstraintLayout contain = this;
            ConstraintSet viewSet = new ConstraintSet();
            viewSet.clone(contain);
            viewSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,contain.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,20);
            viewSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,contain.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,20);
            viewSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,contain.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,20);
            viewSet.connect(view.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,contain.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,20);
            viewSet.applyTo(contain);
        }
    }
```

The Result:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT4RK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from issueTracker of google, we can creat status tag "new" on constructor, then use it in onAttachToWindow